# Segue found in XML but not found in code

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, segue

Hi I have a question about segue, I have checked many post up here, and pretty sure i have setup the segue properly. And here's my storyboard XML, There's two scenes, SplashScreen and ViewController. Splash Screen has a segue called "startSegue" as seen from the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6751" systemVersion="14C109" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6736"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Splash Screen-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController autoresizesArchivedViewToFullSize="NO" automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" modalTransitionStyle="crossDissolve" id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="SplashScreen" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="YHw-QP-f7w"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="2PH-gO-d5q"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="CXr-Vc-KGH">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                    <extendedEdge key="edgesForExtendedLayout"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="dqe-cT-PeC" kind="push" identifier="startSegue" id="bcv-Eq-8U6"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="306" y="314"/>
        </scene>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="Pnt-X0-2I5">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="dqe-cT-PeC" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="w8K-7E-bqp"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="Nj4-1u-ozE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="r7Q-nY-3Gv">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="yAf-Ru-F3U" customClass="PreviewView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="F3Y-vZ-LGa"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="n7E-NZ-nYo" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1021" y="314"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

But When I call the code to perform the segue, it got an error and said 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'startSegue''

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"startSegue" sender: self];
```

Used try-catch pair to check, it is not related to navigationController issue.

BTW I setup the SplashScreen with the following code in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.viewController = [[SplashScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreen" bundle:nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you call performSegueWithIdentifier from the SplashScreen class ?

Comment: Your XML file is a Storyboard file. To load the initial controller, you should use [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"name" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateInitialViewController];

Comment: Thank you! I haven't test your suggestion, the answers below worked fine (removing all init codes) Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the introduction of Storyboard, you don't need to manually create your first view controller. All you have to do is to specify it in the project properties:

[image]

In your AppDelegate, you can now remove all the initialization code that you added:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // The root view controller is already set. 
    return YES;
}
```

So what was happening in your code? The following line of code was creating a new SplashScreen controller without any view:

```
[[SplashScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreen" bundle:nil];
```

Since SplashScreen is a Storyboard file and not a Nib/Xib file, it was not loaded and returned a `nil` view. When searching for the specified segue, none was found since the Storyboard was not loaded properly.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! Removing all extra codes and it worked perfectly. The rest that I need to do is to move over the SpalshScreen.XIB element to the storyboard, OR adding a view in the first view controller to load in the XIB. Thanks tonnes !

Comment: people who want to load a xib that u build already onto a view inside storyboard, you can check this view but paul solt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upGJgEPbQMw